# Select rows based on latest date with multiple joins -Code Ignitor

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

My code is running correctly but very slowly:

My code is:

```
    $this->db->select('BaseTbl.id');
    $this->db->from('tbl_all_calls as BaseTbl');
    $this->db->join('tbl_remark_info1 as Remarks','Remarks.id = (select max(id) from 
    tbl_remark_info1 as e2 where e2.cid=BaseTbl.id)','left');

    $this->db->where('BaseTbl.callcode', $num);
    $this->db->where('BaseTbl.deskid', $deskid);
    $this->db->where('Remarks.remarkDate<=',date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->db->where('Remarks.taken', 1);
    $this->db->where('BaseTbl.createdDtm!=', date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->db->group_by('BaseTbl.mobile');
    $this->db->order_by('remarkDate', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->num_rows();      
    return $result;
```

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: did you check running this sql in mysql?

Comment: if you are only returning the count then why you need order, or group by, because total num_rows will be one value or?

Comment: yes running in sql but running slow. can you give query in CI which return latest record in joining table.

Comment: Give index to table fields it increase execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding index to following columns, as it'll increase search speed remarkably.

```
    Remarks.id
    Remarks.taken
    BaseTbl.deskid
    e2.cid
```

Comment: can you provide example to create indexing.